# How to get value from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

A function which is returning data in objects format. I want to get the single value from this object but it is returning undefined. This is my code.

```
var todayEvents = plugin.getDateEvents(day);
var str = JSON.stringify(todayEvents);
console.log(str);
```

This is how it is displaying in console.

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "2020-07-14T14:29:53.525Z",
    "endDate": 1594823393525,
    "summary": "Visit of the Louvre",
    "status": "pending"
  }
]
```

I want to get value of status from this object. I tried like this but it is returning undefined value.

```
str.status
str[0].status
```

Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: `str[0].status` since you have an array

Comment: try str[0].status .will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to get by 0th index.so you get like this str[0] object

to access the name property you do the following way.

**str[0].status**

```js
let str = [
  {
    "startDate": "2020-07-14T14:29:53.525Z",
    "endDate": 1594823393525,
    "summary": "Visit of the Louvre",
    "status": "pending"
  }
];

//then you can access like this
console.log(str[0].status);
```

Answer (score 0):

access the object in the variable first and then the properties

```js
object=[
  {
    "startDate": "2020-07-14T14:29:53.525Z",
    "endDate": 1594823393525,
    "summary": "Visit of the Louvre",
    "status": "pending"
  }
]

console.log(object[0].status)
```

Comment: it is still displaying undefined for me. I do not know what is wrong with this.

Comment: make a jsfiddle and add your code in it and i will check it out for you

Comment: I added some code in my question. This may will help you to understand the issue. It is working in above code snippet. This is only happening in my website code.

Comment: ok run this code `Array.isArray(str)`  and let me know what get in console

Comment: It has returned false.

Comment: like I expected, it means your object is not an array try accessing it like this `str.status` and let me know what you get

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and this is a small issue but taking time. This str.status has returned undefined for me.

Comment: no problem, now that might be because your object is nested do you print your object in browser console or node console?

Comment: I am displaying this in browser console.

Comment: can you take a screenshot